# Limit feature dimensionality in new observations

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, conv-neural-network, pca

I recently started performing feature extraction tests using Tensorflow and Keras in a Python environment and my current scenario involves extracting features from an image dataset comprised of 19012 samples.

For this, I am using a headerless `VGG16` network, which extracts feature vectors of size `4096`. In order to reduce dimensionality and potentially increase performance in future steps that are based around computing the cosine distance between two feature vectors, I applied the `PCA` function with `num_components = 50` and so far this worked relatively well. At this point, I have a dictionary with 19012 `50`-sized feature vectors.

My current problem arises when I try to extract the features of a completely new image for comparison, because I can no longer use `PCA` to keep only the same `50` components kept before.

Is there a way to understand what components were kept in the `PCA` function and apply those rules to new data processed through `VGG16`?

Feature Extraction Code:

```
# Looping through dataset
for file in dataset:
    # Preprocesses image
    logo = data_preprocessing.image_preprocessing(data_dir + file, 224, 224)
    # Extracting the feature vector and appending to dictionary
    features = feature_extraction.extract_features(logo, model)
    data[file] = features
if usePca:
    # Generates list of features
    filenames = np.array(list(data.keys()))
    features = np.array((list(data.values())))
    features = features.reshape(-1, 4096)
    # applies PCA (4096 -> 50)
    pca = PCA(n_components=50, random_state=22)
    pca.fit(features)
    pcadata = pca.transform(features)
    # Creating new Dictionary from filenames and pcadata
    data = {dataset[i]: pcadata[i] for i in range(len(filenames))}
```

Feature Extraction with built-in PCA (this causes the traceback):

```
    def dimensionality_reduced_feats(reshaped_img, model):
    # preparing image for the model
    img = preprocess_input(reshaped_img)
    # get the full dimension feature vector
    features = model.predict(img, use_multiprocessing=True)
    features = features.reshape(-1, 4096)
    # Apply PCA = 50
    pca = PCA(n_components=50, random_state=22)
    pca.fit(features)
    feats = pca.transform(features)
    return feats
```

Traceback

```
    img1_feats = dimensionality_reduced_feats(img1, model)
  File "C:\Users\jjoao\PycharmProjects\GSEFeatures\feature_extraction\image_comparison.py", line 55, in dimensionality_reduced_feats
    pca.fit(features)
  File "C:\Users\jjoao\PycharmProjects\GSEFeatures\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\_pca.py", line 382, in fit
    self._fit(X)
  File "C:\Users\jjoao\PycharmProjects\GSEFeatures\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\_pca.py", line 457, in _fit
    return self._fit_full(X, n_components)
  File "C:\Users\jjoao\PycharmProjects\GSEFeatures\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\_pca.py", line 475, in _fit_full
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: n_components=50 must be between 0 and min(n_samples, n_features)=1 with svd_solver='full'
```

Comment: yes, you need to save the PCA transformer. Also, PCA doesn't throw away any components, it will make new one, based on linear combinations of the original space. Please share code, so we can show examples code

Comment: After pca.fit(features), the pca refers to a learned transformation, and you can re-apply it to new data